# Populate list dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-widgets

Using jQuery FancyList from http://jquerywidgets.com/widgets/fancy-list/

I am trying to insert a `<li>` through code, not by a user click action.

My issue lies in the `this` keyword, specifically the following lines:

```
    $(".fancy-list-footer .add").click( function() {
        $('.tab-container .user-information .first-name:last').val('').removeClass('placeholder');
        $('.tab-container .user-information .last-name:last').val('').removeClass('placeholder');
        fancyList($(this));
    });
```

I would like to be able to pass a first name and last name without having to populate the textboxes - a for loop will do this.

I tried changing the `fancyList(elem)` function to `fancyList(elem, firstName, lastName)` but I couldn't seem to get the correct value for elem - I tried `var elem = document.getElementByClassName('fancy-list-footer')` because I thought that's what the `$(this)` referred to in the button click, but this didn't work either.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEYaqa?editors=101

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function like so that will add a name:

```
function addToFancyList(first_name, last_name) {
    $('.fancy-list').find(".fancy-list-content-list:last").append("<li><div class='person'><span class = 'first'>" + first_name + "</span><span class = 'last'>" + last_name + "</span></div><div class='clear'></div></li>");
}
```

And simply call it like so:

```
$(function () {
    addToFancyList('Tom', 'Someone');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer relies in the function itself. here is the implementation of fancyList from the link you send:

```
        function fancyList(elem) {

        var this_parent = elem.parents(".fancy-list");

        rel = this_parent.attr("rel");
                var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;

        first_name = this_parent.find(".fancy-list-footer input#fancy-list-first-name").val().replace(/[<\s]/g, "").replace(/[>\s]/g, "");
        last_name = this_parent.find(".fancy-list-footer input#fancy-list-last-name").val().replace(/[<\s]/g, "").replace(/[>\s]/g, "");

        // more lines of code...
```

but it can easly change to this:

```
        function fancyList(elem, first_name, last_name ) {

        var this_parent = elem.parents(".fancy-list");

        rel = this_parent.attr("rel");
        var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;

        first_name = first_name .replace(/[<\s]/g, "").replace(/[>\s]/g, "");
        last_name = last_name.replace(/[<\s]/g, "").replace(/[>\s]/g, "");

        // more lines of code...
```

this way the function will better suit your needs and won't force you to generate elements just to get their textual values